# unable to connect to linux machine through socket

Tags: java, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have a a server running on a linux machine with centos 7.
On the machine I run a code the manages client connections to the server.
Here is my code:

```
public class ServerMain_mng {
final static int nPort = 3333;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new ServerMain_mng();
}

public ServerMain_mng(){
    try {
        ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(3333);
        System.out.println("Server started at: " + new Date());
        System.out.println("===============================================\n");

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("waiting for connection");
            //Wait for a client to connect
            Socket socket = sSocket.accept();
            socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
            //Create a new custom thread to handle the connection
            ClientThread cT = new ClientThread(socket, nPort);
            //Start the thread!
            new Thread(cT).start();  
        }
    } 
    catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}}
```

The problem is that the code does not get past the line `Socket socket = sSocket.accept();` when a client tries to connect to the server.

I should note that i run the same code on my laptop, connecting as a client from a local host and it works fine.
I checked the port forwarding in the router and the specified ports are open.

What could be the problem? Any ideas how to fix it?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to check if a firewall is running on your linux machine. Try running `service iptables stop` as root to disable it while you test your server. If that does not work, you should debug your network with wireshark/tcpdump running on your server machine, so you verify 100% that the client connection reaches your linux server (i.e. that port forwarding is working like you think it is)

Comment: I already added the port to the firewall using `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3333/tcp --permanent`.

Comment: Then you need to start debugging your network with tcpdump. Does your server work if you test it from localhost ? Does it work if you test it from another host on the same local network ?  (You can test both of those by using telnet) Does it work if you disable the firewall entierly (It takes a very short amount of time to test that, so ti's worth doing even if the firewall-cmd in theory should have fixed it). The point is you need to narrow down the problem to either your server code(which works fine, since you mention it works on another machine), your server machine, your router,your client

Answer (score 0):

sSocket.accept() is a blocking call, it is supposed to remain blocked untill some client connects to it using the same port where it is listening.

```
 public class Client {
         final static int nPort = 3333;
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         Socket sock=new Socket(IP of Server, nPort)
         System.out.println("connected to: +sock.getRemoteSocketAddress())
      //send additional data needed for the server using the socket's outputputStream
            }
            }
```

At the server,

```
 ClientThread cT = new ClientThread(socket);
  //Start the thread!
  new Thread(cT).start();
```

Comment: I know that. I am trying to connect to it on the specified port but nothing is happening. As i stated, on my laptop it run fine.

Comment: yes. The ClientThread? How will it help you if it never reaches that point?

Comment: You should create the client in a separate process where it connects to the server port and then create another thread in this code to handle the task you want to do.

Comment: ok. why will it act differently? How do you propose i do that? can you give an example?